# Can regex edit a particular word in a particular line by going to the line using some other word from that line

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

Consider the following file:

```
Name    Id    department
some    13    IT
hey     12    IT
```

what I actually want to do is read a name from the user and edit its particular id or department. I am trying to use `sed` to do it However am not able to find the proper regex to replace `IT` only in hey's line

I am relatively new in the field of regex and do not know much other than the very few basics

Comment: Sorry, the original question I asked wasn't the one I should have asked. It has now been edited to fulfill my requirements

Comment: is it tabs as delimiter or multiple spaces?

Comment: Just as a hint: [grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/) as a few nice basic intoductions to things like e.g. `sed`,`awk`, or `bash`.

Comment: @nerd_dude, pLumo's question will become very relevant if the new department contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In sed, prefixing a command with a regex edits only the lines matching that regex.

```bash
sed -r '/^hey\s/s/(\s)IT$/\1whatever/'
```

Comment: I would be tempted to use `s/[^[:blank:]]\+$/whatever/` (using "non-blanks" at the end of the line since we don't care (or perhaps even know) what the previous department is). I'm using the POSIX character class -- I've never been sure about which seds understand the PCRE-esque `\s` notation.

Comment: 1) Use `-E` instead of the GNU-only `-r` for extended regular expressions. 2) Don't use the GNU-only `\s` without explaining that this is not portable code, which won't work on most versions of `sed`

Answer (score 1):

To find a specific line by pattern in `sed` and replace foo with bar, do this:

```
sed '/pattern/s/foo/bar/'
```

Since names seem to be the first column in your case, you can even add the `^`-marker for "start of line" to your pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `awk` instead of `sed` for your task.

If the file is delimited with tab:

```
 awk -F$'\t' '$1=="hey"{$3="HR"}{OFS=FS;print}' file
```

if it's space delimited:

```
awk '$1=="hey"{$3="HR"}1' file | column -t
```

`column -t` is optional for getting a nice output.